# Update list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm a fresher in python. I have some troubles with list.
After creating the list, i update it. it's right when I print each element of list in loop  wrong , but wrong when I return list: all elements of list are same

```
def shift(array,n):
    for i in range(n):
        array.append(array[0])
        array.pop(0)
    return array

def shiftKey(array):
    array_shift = []
    for i in range(16):
        array_shift.append([])

    array_shift[0] = [shift(array[0],1),shift(array[1],1)]
    print (array_shift[0])
    for j in range(1,16):
        if j == 1 or j == 8 or j == 15:
            a1 = shift(array_shift[j-1][0],1)
            a2 = shift(array_shift[j-1][1],1)
            array_shift[j] = [a1,a2]
            print (array_shift[j])
        else:
            a1 = shift(array_shift[j-1][0],2)
            a2 = shift(array_shift[j-1][1],2)
            array_shift[j] = [a1,a2]
            print (array_shift[j])
    return array_shift
shiftKey([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]])
```

and this's the result expected

> [[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5,
>   6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1]] [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
>   11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
>   14, 15, 16, 1, 2]] [[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2,
>   3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4]] [[7,
>   8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]] [[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
>   16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3,
>   4, 5, 6, 7, 8]] [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
>   10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]] [[13,
>   14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16,
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]] [[15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
>   8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12, 13, 14]] [[16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
>   [16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]] [[2, 3, 4, 5,
>   6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
>   10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1]] [[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
>   14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
>   1, 2, 3]] [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>   [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] [[8, 9, 10,
>   11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
>   14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]] [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2,
>   3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
>   7, 8, 9]] [[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
>   [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]] [[13, 14, 15,
>   16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3,
>   4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]

but it's print like below when i print list

> [[[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14,
>   15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
>   6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>   9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
>   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14,
>   15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>   9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], 
>   [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14,
>   15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
>   6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>   9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
>   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14,
>   15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>   9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
>   12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]], 
>   [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14,
>   15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],  [[13, 14, 15, 16, 1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],   [13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
>   6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]]

Comment: How you are calling `shiftKey` function first time?

Comment: sorry, i edited

Comment: There are to major classes of objects in Python, immutable (strings, ints, and tuples, ...) and mutables (list, dicts, ...). Lists are mutable which sort of act like pass by reference. When you are appending lists to your list of lists, you are not actually creating new lists. You are making new pointers to the same list object. You are printing as you are going through the updates, so you see each change occur. When you return the final object, all you have is a list with many pointers, all pointing to the same list object, which is at the place you left it after the last operation.

Comment: Hi, can you edit your test case to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `deepcopy` functionality so you pass a copy of list instead of reference of the list.

Also, you can use the following easy function for rotation:

```
def shift(input_list, rotate):
    return input_list[rotate:] + input_list[:rotate]
```

I will suggest you read about [defaultlist](https://defaultlist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I corrected my code and gave an alternate solution, please try this one.

```
import copy

def shift(array,n):
    for i in range(n):
        array.append(array[0])
        array.pop(0)
    return array

def shiftKey(array):
    array_shift = []
    array_shift.append([shift(array[0],1),shift(array[1],1)])
    print (array_shift[0])
    for j in range(1,16):
        if j == 1 or j == 8 or j == 15:
            a1 = shift(copy.deepcopy(array_shift[j-1][0]),1)
            a2 = shift(copy.deepcopy(array_shift[j-1][1]),1)
            array_shift.append([a1,a2])
            print (array_shift[j])
        else:
            a1 = shift(copy.deepcopy(array_shift[j-1][0]),2)
            a2 = shift(copy.deepcopy(array_shift[j-1][1]),2)
            array_shift.append([a1,a2])
            print (array_shift[j])
    return array_shift

shiftKey([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]])
```

Comment: Thanks.It's working, but the first element is wrong

Comment: Try solution posted above.